ICETOOL returns no records
I have a requirement to copy all records with 'AB0' or 'AB9' starting at column position 8.
My job always returns an empty dataset.
Any pointers to solve this will be of much help!


My job ends with RC=0 but output file is empty.

Looks like your input is VB format which has 4 bytes of RDW upfront. So if you want to  copy all records with 'AB0' or 'AB9' starting at column position 8, then you should check for position 12
INCLUDE COND=(12,03,CH,EQ,C'AB0',OR,
              12,03,CH,EQ,C'AB9')


Yes, I ran as per your suggestion & it woked.
